# Working with immutable HashMap in Scala

Tags: scala, hashmap

I have an immutable HashMap and want to add/remove values from it. The [Scala api docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap) say that I have to use `+=` and `-=` methods, but they don't work and I get the following error:

```
error: value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
```

How do I add or remove values from a HashMap in Scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are watching api for `mutable` HashMap, to add pair to immutable HashMap use `+`

```
hashMap + ("key", "value")
```

or if you want to remove use `-`

```
hashMap - "key"
```

But you should remember that it would create a **new** structure

As for `+=` method, i think that this design is not good, because in such case you have to use `var` instead of `val`, and that's not a functional way

Comment: - or + put alone will not modify hashMap

Comment: @om-nom-nom it will return a new map

Comment: how do I add many keys-values for one time? Like `hashMap + ("key", "value") + ("key2", "value2")`

Comment: by the way, there should be hashMap + ("key" -> "value")

Comment: @MariusKavansky `hashMap ++ Seq("foo" -> "bar", "bar" -> "baz")`

Comment: <console>:10: error: type mismatch; found: String("key") required: (String, ?)

Answer (score 3):

There is no method `+=` in immutable collections, but compiler rewrites constructions like `a <opname>= b` to `a = a <opname> b` if there is no method `<opname>=` in `a`.

```
var myMap = Map[Int, String]()
myMap += (1, "a")
```

Last line actually means:

```
myMap = myMap + (1, "a")
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because immutable map yields new instance instead of modifying existing one (thus it is immutable). So using val with immutable map is not a legal:

```
scala> val foo = Map.empty[Int, Int]
foo: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> foo += 1 -> 2
<console>:9: error: value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int]
              foo += 1 -> 2
                  ^

scala> var bar = Map.empty[Int, Int]
bar: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map()

scala> bar += 2 -> 2

scala> bar
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 2)
```

If you against using vars, opt to mutable maps.